# What does "running in backwards compatibility mode" mean and what should I fix to get rid of it?

Tags: pgfplots, warnings

I was typesetting a Tex file, but I got this warning:

> *! Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.6} into your preamble.*

Now, I know that adding that line to the preamble solves the problem, but my question focuses more on the "why am I getting this" part of the problem.

What should I be looking for in my Tex file? Usually I get a "problem in line X" indication, but here, I'm lost. I don't understand what it is complaining about.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

One of the principles which the LaTeX kernel, and many of the packages outside the kernel, attempt to follow is that documents should look the same (even up to spacing behaviour) when they recompiled on different machines with different package versions, even decades apart.

`pgfplots` is a regularly updated package that frequently adds new features and fixes bugs. This also means that some old documents might look different if recompiled with those new features/bug fixes enabled. Hence `pgfplots` provides a feature whereby you have to explicitly request which version of the package you want to use (or at least essentially, as the package provides backwards compatibility emulation for older versions), and hence which new features and bug fixes you want access to.

This is a "good thing", but it explains your warning - you are not using all the features and bug fixes available to you. Some of the fixes include better placement of tick labels, as mentioned in the warning. This is not enabled by default as it would clearly change how existing documents appear.

> Section 2.2 "Upgrade remarks" of the `pgfplots` manual discusses this.

For completeness, I provide information on selecting the version:

- **Requesting a specific version**

  To request a specific version, just use the `compat` option:

  ```
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
  ```
- **The bleeding edge (discouraged)**

  You may be happy to live on "the bleeding edge" and to always use the most recent bug fixes etc that `pgfplots` provides. `pgfplots` also allows you to specify this, but encourages you **not** to as your document may compile differently before/after updating the package at certain times, and you may not be explicitly aware of the changes or what has caused them.

  Hence, if you choose to select the `newest` version with

  ```
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
  ```

  then `pgfplots` still issues a message (not a warning) to remind you, which you might miss:

  ```
  Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': document has been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}).
  ```

  This notification can also be disabled:

  ```
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=newest,compat/show suggested version=false}
  ```

  Remember though that the `pgfplots` author discourages this! Again, see the manual for the offical information.

Comment: I just ran into this warning and this answer is really satisfying. One issue remains though: how does pgf guess which version it should use to preserve aspect, and how can I check it guessed right?

Comment: If the `pgfplots` manual doesn't help you, then I'm not sure I can either. The only time `pgfplots` guesses a version is when you request `compat=newest` and it tries to estimate which new features you are using and which you are not, to encourage you to request a specific version instead of `newest`. There have been some bugfixes etc that have not preserved compatibility, so loading `compat=X` may not be the same as loading version `X` of the package file as it was when released. For more help, I suggest that you start a new question with a MWE where someone more knowledgeable may find it.

Comment: I was not aware of the behavior you described in your answer, so I was compiling an old document for another install without any `compat=X` and I obviously got the same warning asker did. Maybe my question should be: what version exactly (or what middleground/approach) is used in "backwards compatibility mode" when you don't specify anything, and on what basis does pgf suggest "use `compat=X`" (eg asker got X=1.6 and I got X=1.9)

Comment: If you don't specify any `compat` then you get `compat=default` which is the same as `pre 1.3`. Obviously `pgfplots` cannot suggest a version newer than the version of the `pgfplots` package that is installed, but I don't know the specifics of how `pgfplots` suggests a version. Perhaps if there have been important bugfixes, it suggests newer versions even if it hasn't detected use of certain new features. If you want your document to look close to how it used to look, then find the date of the old document and try the latest `pgfplots` version that was available then!

Comment: The version shown on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots?lang=en) is 1.14. How come it's 1.7 in your example, which would be way newer? I also saw something about version 1.9 somewhere. I'm kind of confused about these version numbers.

Comment: @SkeletonBow: think of the version numbers as dot-separated components, rather than decimal numbers. Since `14 > 9 > 7`, hence `1.14 > 1.9 > 1.7`. Does that help? It's just a case of the leading zeros being implicit (`1.7 = 1.07` etc).

Comment: Oh,  that makes perfect sense. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is gold. Still works. Kills all warnings in one go.