# Highlight extreme values and show dashes for empty values in pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

I am using [@jake](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2552/jake)'s 
[solution to highlight extreme values](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34045/15301) with pgfplotstable.

- doc.tex

  ```
  \documentclass[]{article}
  \input{table.tex}  % table.tex includes Jake's code
  \begin{document}
  \begin{table}[ht]
  \begin{center}
  \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data-1.csv}\data
  \pgfplotstabletypeset[
      column type=r,
      columns/a/.style={column type={l|}, string type},
      every head row/.style={before row=\hline, after row=\hline},
      every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
      empty cells with={\ensuremath{-}},
      highlight col max ={\data}{b},
      highlight col max ={\data}{c},
      highlight col max ={\data}{d},
  ]{\data}
  \end{center}
  \caption{My table.}
  \label{tab:results}
  \end{table}

  \end{document}
  ```
- table.tex

  ```
  \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
      \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}     % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81912/15301


  % [conditional formatting per values](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34045/15301)
  \newcommand{\findmax}[3]{
      \pgfplotstablevertcat{\datatable}{#1}
      \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
      create col/expr={%
      \pgfplotstablerow
      }]{rownumber}\datatable
      \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={#2},sort cmp={float >}]{\sorted}{\datatable}%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{rownumber}\of{\sorted}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro#3{\pgfplotsretval}
      \pgfplotstableclear{\datatable}
  }

  \newcommand{\findmin}[3]{
      \pgfplotstablevertcat{\datatable}{#1}
      \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
        create col/expr={%
      \pgfplotstablerow
      }]{rownumber}\datatable
      \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={#2},sort cmp={float <}]{\sorted}{\datatable}%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{rownumber}\of{\sorted}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro#3{\pgfplotsretval}
      \pgfplotstableclear{\datatable}
  }

  \pgfplotstableset{
      highlight col max/.code 2 args={
          \findmax{#1}{#2}{\maxval}
          \edef\setstyles{\noexpand\pgfplotstableset{
                  every row \maxval\noexpand\space column #2/.style={
                      postproc cell content/.append style={
                          /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={$\noexpand\bf}{$}
                      },
                  }
              }
          }\setstyles
      },
      highlight col min/.code 2 args={
          \findmin{#1}{#2}{\minval}
          \edef\setstyles{\noexpand\pgfplotstableset{
                  every row \minval\noexpand\space column #2/.style={
                      postproc cell content/.append style={
                          /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={\noexpand\color{red}$\noexpand\bf}{$}
                      },
                  }
              }
          }\setstyles
      },
      highlight row max/.code 2 args={
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro\rowindex{#2-1}
          \pgfplotstabletranspose{\transposed}{#1}
          \findmax{\transposed}{\rowindex}{\maxval}
          \edef\setstyles{\noexpand\pgfplotstableset{
                  every row \rowindex\space column \maxval\noexpand/.style={
                      postproc cell content/.append style={
                          /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={$\noexpand\bf}{$}
                      },
                  }
              }
          }\setstyles
      },
      highlight row min/.code 2 args={
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro\rowindex{#2-1}
          \pgfplotstabletranspose{\transposed}{#1}
          \findmin{\transposed}{\rowindex}{\maxval}
          \edef\setstyles{\noexpand\pgfplotstableset{
                  every row \rowindex\space column \maxval\noexpand/.style={
                      postproc cell content/.append style={
                          /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={\noexpand\color{red}$\noexpand\bf}{$}
                      },
                  }
              }
          }\setstyles
      },
  }
  ```

It works well when I fill in all the values in the table:

- data-1.csv

  ```
  a,b,c,d
  x,1,3,5 
  y,2,2,2 
  z,1,1,7
  ```

[image]

And even when there's an `nan`:

- data-2.csv

  ```
  a,b,c,d
  x,1,3,5 
  y,2,2,2 
  z,1,1,nan
  ```

[image]

But instead of `NaN`, I want a dash `-` to mark the empty cell.
So I included `empty cells with={\ensuremath{-}}` in `\pgfplotstabletypeset`, and totally emptied the corresponding cell in the `csv` file. However, in this case, compilation fails:

- data-3.csv

  ```
  a,b,c,d
  x,1,3,5 
  y,2,2,2 
  z,1,1,
  ```

  Error message:

  ```
  ! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near ''..
  ```

If I want to mark my empty cells with a dash as the screenshot below, and yet highlight the maximum values per column as in Jake's code, what can I do?

[image]