# Beamer: Line separator in column

Tags: beamer, columns, pgfornament

I am using [pgfornament](http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/index.html) to draw line separators.

It works perfectly, but in this case, I want to place the line separator inside a column, but I get errors...

This is the MWE I made:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table}, hyperref={unicode}]{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\reserveinserts{28}
\setbeameroption{hide notes}

\mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme{Singapore}
    \usecolortheme{orchid}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}%before tikz
    \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos} %for positioning
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usepackage{graphicx} %Allows including images
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line

    \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,calc,mindmap,trees,shapes,
    decorations.pathreplacing}%calc is already called in the beamerthemeSIgN.sty file!
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81899/what-does-running-in-backwards-compatibility-mode-mean-and-what-should-i-fix-t


    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{multirow}


    %line separator
    \usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
    \newcommand{\sectionline}[3]{%
        \nointerlineskip \vspace{.5\baselineskip}\hspace{\fill}{
            \resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{#3}{
                \pgfornament[color = #1]{#2}
            }
        }
        \hspace{\fill}
        \par\nointerlineskip \vspace{.5\baselineskip}
    }


    \usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif
    \usepackage{fontspec}

    \usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lm
    \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
}


\begin{document}
%\mode* % same as ignorenonframetext

\section{Unit 1}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My title}
\begin{columns}[T] % align columns
\begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{column}%
\hfill%
\begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
    \setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt}
    \begin{itemize}
    \itemsep0.5em
        \item Some text here
    \end{itemize}
    \hspace{30pt} More text here...
    %\sectionline{blue}{88}{0.75ex} %I WANT THIS HERE, BUT DOESN'T WORK!
\end{column}%
\end{columns}
\sectionline{blue}{88}{0.75ex} %IT ONLY WORKS HERE
\begin{itemize}
\itemsep0.5em
    \item more and more and more text
    \item and yes! more text
\end{itemize}

\note{}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

This MWE produces this[image: this].

However, I want the line separator NEXT TO the image, NOT UNDER it...

If I place the line separator inside the column I get the error:

> You can't use `\prevdepth' in horizontal mode.

Any help?

Comment: I don't understand your code. But I've seen that second `\nointerlineskip` was preceded by `\par` and first not. Adding it before first `\nointerlineskip` your code compiles. Although I don't know if the result is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is `! You can't use '\prevdepth' in horizontal mode.` You may add a blank line before `\sectionline` to leave horizontal mode or, as suggested by Ignasi's comment, you may add `\par` before the first call to `\nointerlineskip` into the definition of `\sectionline`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table}, hyperref={unicode}]{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\reserveinserts{28}
\setbeameroption{hide notes}

\mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme{Singapore}
    \usecolortheme{orchid}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}%before tikz
    \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos} %for positioning
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usepackage{graphicx} %Allows including images
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line

    \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,calc,mindmap,trees,shapes,
    decorations.pathreplacing}%calc is already called in the beamerthemeSIgN.sty file!
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81899/what-does-running-in-backwards-compatibility-mode-mean-and-what-should-i-fix-t


    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{multirow}


    %line separator
    \usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
    \newcommand{\sectionline}[3]{%
        \nointerlineskip \vspace{.5\baselineskip}\hspace{\fill}{
            \resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{#3}{
                \pgfornament[color = #1]{#2}
            }
        }
        \hspace{\fill}
        \par\nointerlineskip \vspace{.5\baselineskip}
    }


    \usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif
    \usepackage{fontspec}

    \usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lm
    \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
}


\begin{document}
%\mode* % same as ignorenonframetext

\section{Unit 1}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My title}
\begin{columns}[T] % align columns
\begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}

    \sectionline{orange}{88}{0.75ex}
\end{column}%
\hfill%
\begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
    \setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt}
    \begin{itemize}
    \itemsep0.5em
        \item Some text here
    \end{itemize}
    \hspace{30pt} More text here...

    \sectionline{magenta}{88}{0.75ex} %I WANT THIS HERE, BUT DOESN'T WORK!
\end{column}%
\end{columns}
\sectionline{blue}{88}{0.75ex} %IT ONLY WORKS HERE
\begin{itemize}
\itemsep0.5em
    \item more and more and more text
    \item and yes! more text
\end{itemize}

\note{}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh that easy? Why wasn't I aware of this? Many thanks!!

Comment: Are your answer and my comment equivalent solutions?

Comment: @Ignasi A blank line and `\par` are equivalent. But your solution seems more robust in current context.