# Recreating a figure with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to recreate 
[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.35\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-.1,xmax=1.1,ymin=-.1,ymax=1.1,
            axis lines=center,
            ticks=none,
            unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
            xlabel=$u$, ylabel=$v$,
            every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
            every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
          ]
          \addplot [very thick, blue, smooth, domain=(-.2:.2+pi/2)] ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))});
          \addplot [black] plot coordinates {(0,0) (1,.839)}; %% 40 degrees
          \addplot [very thick, blue] plot coordinates {(.766,0) (.766,.643)}; %% 40 degrees
          \addplot [black] plot coordinates {(1,0) (1,.839)}; %% 40 degrees 
          \addplot [black,smooth, domain=(0:40)] ({.15*cos(x)},{.15*sin(x)});
          \node at (axis cs:.15,.07) [anchor=west] {$x$};
          \node at (axis cs:.766,.322) [anchor=east] {$\sin(x)$};
          \node at (axis cs:.383,0) [anchor=north] {$\cos(x)$};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.35\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
  \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-.1,xmax=1.1,ymin=-.1,ymax=1.1,
            axis lines=center,
            ticks=none,
            unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
            xlabel=$u$, ylabel=$v$,
            every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
            every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
          ]
          \addplot [very thick, blue, smooth, domain=(-.2:.2+pi/2)] ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))});
          \addplot [black] plot coordinates {(0,0) (1,.839)}; %% 40 degrees
          \addplot [black] plot coordinates {(.766,0) (.766,.643)}; %% 40 degrees
          \addplot [black] plot coordinates {(1,0) (1,.839)}; %% 40 degrees
          \addplot [black,smooth, domain=(0:40)] ({.15*cos(x)},{.15*sin(x)});
          \addplot [very thick,blue] plot coordinates {(0,0) (.766,.643)}; %% sector
          \addplot [very thick,blue] plot coordinates {(0,0) (1,0)}; %% sector
          \addplot [very thick, blue, smooth, domain=(0:40)] ({cos(x)},{sin(x)}); %% sector
          \node at (axis cs:.15,.07) [anchor=west] {$x$};
          \node at (axis cs:.5,0) [anchor=north] {$1$};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.35\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \begin{axis}[clip=false,
            xmin=-.1,xmax=1.1,ymin=-.1,ymax=1.1,
            axis lines=middle,
            xlabel=$u$, ylabel=$v$,
            ticks=none,
            unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
            every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
            every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
          ]
          \addplot [very thick, blue, smooth, domain=(-.1:1.671)] ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))});
          \addplot [very thick, blue] plot coordinates {(0,0) (1,.839)}; %% 40 degrees
          \addplot [black] plot coordinates {(.766,0) (.766,.643)}; %% 40 degrees
          \addplot [very thick, blue] plot coordinates {(1,0) (1,.839)}; %% 40 degrees
          \addplot [black,smooth, domain=(0:40)] ({.15*cos(x)},{.15*sin(x)});
          \node at (axis cs:.15,.07) [anchor=west] {$x$};
          \node at (axis cs:.5,0) [anchor=north] {$1$};
          \node at (axis cs:1,.42) [anchor=west] {$\tan(x)$};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

My problem is with `labels` and `shading`.

Comment: Have a look at the [pgfmanual](http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) chapter 2 (Tutorial: A Picture for Karl’s Students). There you find all the information you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you're adding `\caption`s to each diagram, I don't think you need the `minipage`s. In fact, you can make do with a single `tikzpicture`. While possible to do with three `axis` environments (you can set the position with `at={<coordinate>}`), the `groupplot` environment from the `groupplots` library is made for this type of thing.

It simplifies the code as you can set common settings for the axes just once. I also defined some styles for drawing, filling and nodes, and I defined a function `A` for the angle. All coordinates are then defined using `cos(A)`/`sin(A)`/`tan(A)`, instead of the decimal values you had. This way you can easily change the angle as well -- modify the value for `A` and the whole diagram changes.

By the way, there are a couple of oddities in your code. The documented way of setting the domain is with `domain=0:40`, no parentheses (even though it actually works with them). And you're using `\addplot plot coordinates`, which is mixing the TikZ syntax `\draw plot coordinates` with `pgfplots` syntax `\addplot coordinates`. The `plot` keyword is not needed here.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
% with compat=1.11 or higher, you don't have to specify "axis cs:" for coordinates in e.g. \node
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   % parameterise the angle
   declare function={A=40;},
   % for labels sin(x), cos(x), tan(x), 1
   triglabels/.style={left,black,font=\footnotesize,inner sep=4pt},
   % for outlines
   blueline/.style={very thick, draw=blue},
   % for filling
   filling/.style={fill=blue!10},
   % for Triangle A/B, Sector, below axes
   caption/.style={below=2mm,font=\itshape}
]

\begin{groupplot}[
            group style={
              group size=3 by 1, % 3 columns in 1 row
              horizontal sep=5mm, 
              group name=T % name used at the end
            },
            % the following settings apply to all three axes
            xmin=-.1,xmax=1.1,
            ymin=-.1,ymax=1.1,
            axis lines=center,
            ticks=none,
            unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
            xlabel=$u$, ylabel=$v$,
            every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
            every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
            % set default domain
            domain=-.1:.1+pi/2,
            % set clip=false to avoid clipping of nodes
            clip=false,
          ]

   \nextgroupplot
          % draw arc
          \addplot [blueline] ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))});

          % draw tan(A) triangle
          \addplot [black] coordinates {(0,0) (1,{tan(A)}) (1,0)}; 

          % draw and fill triangle
          \addplot [blueline,filling] coordinates {(0,0) ({cos(A)},0) ({cos(A)},{sin(A)}) (0,0)};
          % add labels
          \node [triglabels,below] at ({cos(A)/2},0)        {$\cos(x)$};
          \node [triglabels,left]  at ({cos(A)},{sin(A)/2}) {$\sin(x)$}; 

          % angle
          \addplot [black,domain=0:A] ({.15*cos(x)},{.15*sin(x)})
               node[triglabels,right,midway] {$x$};


   \nextgroupplot

          % draw arc
          \addplot [blueline] ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))});
          \addplot [black] coordinates {(1,0) (1,{tan(A)}) (0,0)}; 

          % do the filling in two steps, note \closedcycle
          \addplot [filling] coordinates {(0,0) ({cos(A)},{sin(A)})} \closedcycle;
          \addplot [filling,domain=0:A]  ({cos(x)},{sin(x)})         \closedcycle;

          % draw the two sector lines, add "1"label along the way
          \addplot [blueline] coordinates {({cos(A)},{sin(A)}) (0,0) (1,0)}
               node[triglabels,below,pos=0.75] {$1$}; 
          % then draw the arc
          \addplot [blueline,domain=0:A] ({cos(x)},{sin(x)}); 

          % angle
          \addplot [black,domain=0:A] ({.15*cos(x)},{.15*sin(x)})
               node[triglabels,right,midway] {$x$};


   \nextgroupplot
          % draw and fill triangle
          \addplot [blueline,filling] coordinates {(0,0) (1,0) (1,{tan(A)}) (0,0)};
          % add labels
          \node [triglabels,below] at (0.5,0) {$1$};
          \node [triglabels,right] at (1,{tan(A)/2}) {$\tan(x)$};
          % black line
          \addplot [black] coordinates {({cos(A)},{sin(A)}) ({cos(A)},0)}; 
          % draw arc on top of filling
          \addplot [very thick, blue,] ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))});

          % angle
          \addplot [black, domain=0:A] ({.15*cos(x)},{.15*sin(x)})
               node[triglabels,right,midway] {$x$};


\end{groupplot}

 % add labels below axes
  \node [caption] at (T c1r1.outer south) {Triangle A};
  \node [caption] at (T c2r1.outer south) {Sector};
  \node [caption] at (T c3r1.outer south) {Triangle B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Really nice! Where are `c1r1`, `c3r1` and `c3r1` defined? Perhaps they come for free from the `groupplot`?

Comment: @Andrew  Yes, they come for free. With `group name=T` in the `group style`, the axes are automatically named `T c<col num>r<row num>`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}` is creating an error. what should I do?

Comment: @marya Remove it altogether, set `compat=newest` to automatically select the most recent one available, or use `\documentclass{standalone} \usepackage{pgfplots} \begin{document} \pgfplotsversion \end{document}` to figure out which version of `pgfplots` you have, and use that version number.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81899/ and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139690 for some more about `compat` setting.