# How to remove minor tick marks while keeping grid lines?

Tags: pgfplots, ticks

I have created the following plot, but I am unable to remove the minor *y ticks* on the **y-axis** and keeping the grid lines. Is there any method to achieve this?

I searched for a solution, but I believe there is none. Any help is appreciated.
You can find the code and figure below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lmodern} %font size, could use less than 1pt font
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
% use helvet font
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.3}
\pgfplotsset{width=\textwidth, height=5.8cm}
\pgfplotsset{scaled y ticks=false} %no scientific notation at y axis 

\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
\sisetup{per=slash, load=abbr}

%define the colour values
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{192,0,0} %red
\definecolor{grey}{RGB}{175,171,171} %grey
\definecolor{purple}{RGB}{112,48,160} %purple
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{2,112,192} %darkblue

\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{5,111,255} %darkblue
\definecolor{brown}{RGB}{148,102,52} %darkblue
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{96,186,69} %darkblue

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture} 

% define font size
\def \titlefont {12}
\def \labelfont {12}
\def \tickfont {12}
\def \legendfont {12}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,]{Data.csv}\datatable

    \begin{axis}[
        align =center,
        title style={font=\bfseries\fontsize{\titlefont}{\titlefont}\selectfont}, 
        grid=both, 
        grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
        major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
        minor tick num=9,
        ymin=0, 
        ymax=25,
        xmode=log,
        log ticks with fixed point,
        ylabel={Time (s)},
        xlabel={Number of Processes},
        y label style={font=\fontsize{\labelfont}{\labelfont}\selectfont}, 
        x label style={font=\fontsize{\labelfont}{\labelfont}\selectfont}, 
        xtick=data,
        x tick label style={font=\fontsize{\labelfont}{\labelfont}\selectfont},
        y tick label style={font=\fontsize{\labelfont}{\labelfont}\selectfont},
        xtick pos=bottom,ytick pos=left,
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\boldmath\fontsize{\tickfont}{\tickfont}\selectfont,/pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/precision=1},
        nodes near coords align={vertical},% configure node position
        legend style={font=\fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont},
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.25)},anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
        ]

        \addplot[very thick, 
        every node near coord/.append style={yshift=0.0cm, font=\boldmath\fontsize{\tickfont}{\tickfont}\selectfont,/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=1, red}, 
        mark=star, mark size=2, red] 
        table[x=N, y expr=\thisrow{K1}, col sep=comma]
        {\datatable};

        \addplot[very thick, 
        every node near coord/.append style={yshift=0.0cm, font=\boldmath\fontsize{\tickfont}{\tickfont}\selectfont,/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=1, red}, 
        mark=triangle, mark size=2, blue] 
        table[x=N, y expr=\thisrow{K3}, col sep=comma] 
        {\datatable};

        \addplot[very thick, 
        every node near coord/.append style={yshift=0.0cm, font=\boldmath\fontsize{\tickfont}{\tickfont}\selectfont,/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=1, red}, 
        mark=square, mark size=2, black] 
        table[x=N, y expr=\thisrow{K8}, col sep=comma] 
        {\datatable};

        \addplot[very thick, 
        every node near coord/.append style={yshift=0.0cm, font=\boldmath\fontsize{\tickfont}{\tickfont}\selectfont,/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=1, red}, 
        mark=diamond, mark size=2, brown] 
        table[x=N, y expr=\thisrow{K10}, col sep=comma]
        {\datatable};

        \legend{A, B, C, D}

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Thread_Scaling]

I have added the content of **Data.csv** below.

```
N, K1, K3, K8, K10
2,22,19,8, 7
4,20,16,6, 5
8,18,13,5, 4
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Add `no marks` key in axis definition (somewhere between brackets of `\begin{axis}[...]`)

Comment: Your solution provides me a way to remove the marks at each point and remove the x-axis grid lines. I only require a method to modify the y-axis s.t. the y-axis has the major and minor grid lines but removes the minor tick marks on the y-axis. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot compile you code since you have not included the `Data.csv` with values for the plot. But try to write `ytick=\empty` instead.

Comment: Sorry about that. Now I have edited the question to add the contents of Data.csv.

Comment: Add the key `ytick style={draw=none}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hide the ticks but keep the grid lines, you need to add the line

```
ytick style={draw=none},
```

as an option in axis definition (somewhere between brackets of `\begin{axis}[...]`)

[image]

If only the minor tick marks are needed to be removed, but keeping the tick marks for the major grid lines, one can use option `minor tick style={draw=none}`.

**P.S.:** Unless something is wrong, use latest `compat` version `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}` instead of `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}`. For further information, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81912/125434).

Comment: Thank you very much. And if only the minor tick marks needed to be removed (keeping the tick marks for the major grid lines 10 and 20) we can use "minor y tick style={draw=none}," instead.

Comment: @SabraOssen No, the correct option would be `minor tick style={draw=none}`.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the clarification. I was specifically targeting the y-axis minor ticks.